# "Conservative" approximation of a vector field

Tags: calculus, analysis, vector-fields, approximation-theory

Consider a vector field $f\colon \mathbb{R}^2 \to \mathbb{R}^2$ defined as
$$
(x_1, x_2) \mapsto f(x_1,x_2) = \left(\frac{\alpha}{\alpha+x_2^m}-\beta x_1,\frac{\alpha}{\alpha+x_1^m}-\beta x_2\right)
$$
where $\alpha$, $\beta$ are real positive numbers and $m>1$ is an integer number.

> **My question.** The vector field $f$ is clearly not [conservative](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conservative_vector_field). However, is it possible to find a "good approximation" of $f$ that is conservative?

For "good approximation" I mean any vector field $\tilde f$ that is close to $f$ with respect to some metric.

Any comment is welcome. Thanks!

Comment: The condition $\nabla\times f=0$, which is necessary for conservative vector fields, is "closed". By this I mean that, if $\nabla \times f_n=0$ and $f_n \to f$ in some sense that implies $\nabla\times f_n \to \nabla \times f$, then $\nabla \times f=0$. This suggests that you cannot approximate nonconservative vector fields with conservative ones, at least with modes of convergence strong enough to imply convergence of the first derivatives.

Answer (score 4):

This doesn't work for your particular $\mathbf{F}$, but under suitable regularity and growth assumptions, the minimizer of 
$$\frac{1}{2}\int \lvert\boldsymbol{\nabla}\phi(\mathbf{x}')+\mathbf{F}(\mathbf{x'})\rvert^2\mathrm{d}V_{\mathbf{x'}}$$

is the solenoidal component of the Helmholtz decomposition of $\mathbf{F}$

$$\begin{align}\phi(\mathbf{x})&=\int G(\mathbf{x}-\mathbf{x'})\boldsymbol{\nabla}\cdot\mathbf{F}(\mathbf{x}')\mathrm{d}V_{\mathbf{x}'}\\
-\nabla^2G(\mathbf{x}-\mathbf{x}')&=\delta(\mathbf{x}-\mathbf{x}')\text{.}
\end{align}$$
We can interpret $-\boldsymbol{\nabla}\phi$ as an $L^2$ "projection" of $\mathbf{F}$ onto the linear space of conservative vector fields.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Could you please provide a reference for this? In particular, what assumptions are needed?